¿Cómo puedo hacer que un botón recargue una página en HTML y JavaScript?
Estoy buscando una forma de recargar una página web cuando el usuario hace clic en un botón. ¿Cuáles son las mejores prácticas para lograr esto? ¿Debo usar window.location.reload() o document.location.reload()? Además, ¿cómo puedo asegurarme de que la página se recargue desde el principio y no mantenga la posición de desplazamiento actual?
Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Evita preguntar por mejores prácticas ya que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas. Además, céntrate solo en un problema.

Pregunta relacionada: Como recargar una pagina con JS.

Analizando individualmente lo que cada uno propone y su propósito:
window.location.reload recargará la página actual utilizando la caché del navegador y el lado negativo es que si la página tiene contenido dinámico y se ha actualizado desde la última recarga, el contenido no será recargado.
Y document.location.reload forzará una recarga completa de la página directamente desde el servidor, ignorando la caché, y el contenido más reciente se cargará aunque esté en caché. La desventaja de usar esto es que siempre se obtiene la versión más actualizada de la página, lo que puede resultar en un tiempo de carga mayor, ya que todo el contenido necesita descargarse nuevamente del servidor.
Además, cualquier estado de la página se perderá en la recarga, como datos en un formulario que no hayan sido enviados.
document.location.reload
window.location.reload

La mejor práctica no te puedo decir, pero el siguiente código te carga la página desde el principio independientemente del scroll.
<a href="javascript:(window.location.href =window.location.href)">Actualizar página</a>

